# Copying file without previous meta data

Tags: python, copy

I'm doing multiple copies of a file with the following command:

```
shutil.copy2(oldFile, newFile)
```

And rather than returning the creation date of the newly created file, it's keeping the older one. I'm retrieving the date with:

```
dateCreated = os.path.getctime(newFile)
```

I thought this was due to the function being `copy2` which carries over meta data I believe, so I tried it with just `copy` to no avail.

However the odd thing is that the 'Data Modified' tab in a Windows Explorer is showing the correct date and time.

Comment: Windows shows modified time. [os.path.getmtime](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime)

Comment: Unlike in unix where `ctime` refers to the last changed time, on Windows `ctime` refers to the creation time (see http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime). As comment above suggest, try `os.path.getmtime()`.

Comment: When I click properties on the file, it shows the same date for both modified and creation. I'm also running the script over and over, creating 100 copies and they're the same everytime.

Comment: [`shutil.copy2`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) is meant to do that. Are you sure you're getting that behaviour even with [`shutil.copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)?

Comment: Yes indeed. I've just discovered that if you do a copy and the file already exists, it does nothing. So even after deleting the last 100 copies and emptying the trash, it's just shown me: Copy 1 at  Fri Jan 27 13:51:01 2012, copy 64 at Fri Jan 27 13:44:39 2012 and copy 99 at Fri Jan 27 13:51:02 2012. I'm so confused.

Comment: I've just ramped it from 100 to 500 and it appears to be correct now. Still unsure what's happened though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the test I tried just now, I see the following behaviour:

```
test.txt -> Created: Tuesday, January 24, 2012 2:52 PM
         -> Modified: Tuesday, January 24, 2012 2:52 PM

>>> from shutil import *
>>> copy('test.txt','test1.txt')
```

With no pre-existing version of test1.txt in the directory I get:

```
test1.txt -> Created: Today 8:54 AM
          -> Modified: Today 8:54 AM
```

I then delete test1.txt and run:

```
>>> copy2('test.txt','test1.txt')
```

With no pre-existing version of test1.txt in the directory I get:

```
test1.txt -> Created: Tuesday, January 24, 2012 2:52 PM
          -> Modified: Tuesday, January 24, 2012 2:52 PM
```

I then run:

```
>>> copy('test.txt','test1.txt')
```

So with a pre-existing version of test1.txt in the directory I get:

```
test1.txt -> Created: Tuesday, January 24, 2012 2:52 PM
          -> Modified: Today 9:00 AM
```

I then run:

```
>>> copy('test.txt','test1.txt')
```

So with a pre-existing version of test1.txt in the directory I get:

```
test1.txt -> Created: Tuesday, January 24, 2012 2:52 PM
          -> Modified: Today 9:01 AM
```

This is the behaviour you're seeing, your quote:

> I thought this was due to the function being copy2 which carries over meta data I believe, so I tried it with just copy to no avail.

To get a new creation date you're going to have to actively remove the file before you create a new version of it using either `copy` or `copyfile`.  Otherwise the `date created` will remain from it's original time of creation. **`copyfile`** evokes the same behaviour as `copy` with respect to `date creation`.

Comment: Excellent investigation and I thank you for confirming what I'm seeing. However just one question. When you say I'll have to `actively remove the file before you create a new version` are you referring to the `test.txt`? If so wouldn't that mean for 500 copies I'd have to remove and recreate `test.txt` 500 times? Or have I missed a trick?

Comment: If `test.txt` is your originating file and you want to copy it to `test1.txt, ..., test500.txt` I think you're good to go with `copy` as long as none of the `test1.txt, ..., test500.txt` files already exist in your directory (i.e. don't delete 'test.txt'). Your observed behaviour I think is due to having run `copy2` to create `test1.txt` then trying `copy` without removing `test1.txt` first. Let me know if that's making sense.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm following you now. I've just added a quick `if os.path.exists(file)` to my code as a checker, if it exists I'm adding my unique identifier twice. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks for clearing up a couple of hours confusion!

Comment: Nooo! `from shutil import *`
Don't do import *, do `from shutil import copy` or `import shutil` the `shutil.copy(a, b)`

Comment: Windows has a "feature" whereby the existing file meta data is applied to a recently created or renamed file.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172190, there is apparently a registry entry to disable this, or you can simply delay the creation of the new file long enough and it won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one note regarding:

> To get a new creation date you're going to have to actively remove the
>   file before you create a new version of it using either copy or
>   copyfile. Otherwise the date created will remain from it's original
>   time of creation.

I wanted to write a script that makes a backup of some files and rollover files if there are more then n backups.
When you remove the existing file manualy e.g. by 'del c:\test.txt' from other CMD window then running the script, and then run the script that makes a backup, the file gets new ctime. Otherwise, if the file with same name existed and you want to create a copy, the ctime will be somehow the same as in the deleted file.

I wrote an example:
test.py:

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

f_path = 'c:\\test.txt'

print f_path
print 'ctime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(f_path)))
print 'mtime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f_path)))

print ''

bkp_file = f_path + '.bkp'
print 'copying to ' + bkp_file
shutil.copyfile(f_path, bkp_file)
print 'ctime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(bkp_file)))
print 'mtime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(bkp_file)))

print ''
print 'removing backup...'
os.remove(bkp_file)
print 'os.path.exists(bkp_file) = ' + str(os.path.exists(bkp_file))
print ''
print 'copying to ' + bkp_file
shutil.copyfile(f_path, bkp_file)
print 'ctime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(bkp_file)))
print 'mtime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(bkp_file)))
print ''
print 'removing backup again...'
os.remove(bkp_file)
print 'os.path.exists(bkp_file) = ' + str(os.path.exists(bkp_file))

import tempfile
tmp = tempfile.mktemp(dir='c:\\')
print ''
print 'Created temp file name - ' + tmp

print 'Copying to temp file name...'
shutil.copyfile(f_path, tmp)
print 'ctime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(tmp)))
print 'mtime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(tmp)))

print ''
print 'renaming file to the same name as the one already deleted'
shutil.move(tmp, bkp_file)

print 'ctime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(bkp_file)))
print 'mtime = ' + str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(bkp_file)))
```

output when file never existed (or deleted in different CMD window)

```
c:\test.py 
c:\test.txt
ctime = 2014-04-30 14:43:41.649976
mtime = 2014-05-05 11:19:19.344976

copying to c:\test.txt.bkp
ctime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.281976
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.282976

removing backup... os.path.exists(bkp_file) = False

copying to c:\test.txt.bkp
ctime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.281976
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.284976

removing backup again... os.path.exists(bkp_file) = False

Created temp file name - c:\tmpn5ofid Copying to temp file name...
ctime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.311976
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.312976

renaming file to the same name as the one already deleted 
ctime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.281976
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.312976

C:\>
```

output when script started second time in one CMD window

```
C:\>test.py
c:\test.txt
ctime = 2014-04-30 14:43:41.649976
mtime = 2014-05-05 11:19:19.344976

copying to c:\test.txt.bkp

ctime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.281976  # ctime of old file
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:21:58.179976

removing backup... os.path.exists(bkp_file) = False

copying to c:\test.txt.bkp
ctime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.281976  # ctime of old file that does not exist
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:21:58.190976

removing backup again... os.path.exists(bkp_file) = False

Created temp file name - c:\tmpzi2lp2 Copying to temp file name...
ctime = 2014-05-05 12:21:58.222976
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:21:58.222976

renaming file to the same name as the one already deleted
ctime = 2014-05-05 12:19:38.281976  # after renaming existing file it gets old ctime  
mtime = 2014-05-05 12:21:58.222976

C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile): "[This copies] the contents (**no metadata**) of the file named src to a file named dst."